# Ajax call to a website url, how I can parse the result and only get the paragraph tags

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call to any url and only use the p tags for the result. How can I implement this?

For instance if I have:

```
$.get("www.foobar.com",function(result){
console.log(result)
});
```

`//this will return all the html contents of foobar.com as a string so I might get <html><head></head><body>
<h1>foobar</h1><h3>Some Text</h3><p>Hello World</p><br><p> this is a cool site</p>`

But I only want the P tag's contents (hello world and this is a cool site) how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple javascript:

```
var str; //Placeholder for string returned from AJAX
var result = ""; //This is where the result will be stored.
var strlength = str.length; //Store end of string

var start = str.indexOf("<p>"); //Position of first <p>;
while(start != -1) //Index will be -1 if no <p> is found
{
  var end = str.indexOf("</p>"); //Position of first </p>
  result += str.slice(start+3, end); //Add section between start and end to result (+3 is to remove <p> from string)
  str = str.slice(end+4, strlength); //New string to check with first section and everythign before it removed (+4 is to move past </p>)
  start = str.indexOf("<p>"); //Get next position
}
```

Note I took you literally on the 'contents' of the 'p' elements. If you want to keep the 'p' tags then change to:

```
result += str.slice(start, end+4);
```

If you want to style the result in some way, then you could add things to the result in between. For example:

```
result += "<br>";
```